# Django: Comment post not allowed (400) Error

Tags: django

i am trying to use django comments on my web application but I get this error:

> Comment post not allowed (400)
>   Why:    Missing content_type or object_pk field.

I am using the following form:

```
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
        {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
        {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ user }}" />
        <input type="text" name="honeypot" size="64" style="display: none;" />
        <textarea id="id_comment" rows="1" cols="40"
                  name="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-post" value="Post" />
</form>
```

but when i use the automatically generated form by django

```
{% render_comment_form for event %}
```

everything works fine. the problem is, i don't want the Name/E-Mail/etc.-Input fields. Only the comment textarea. can someone help me with this problem?

greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message makes it quite clear: you probably failed to include `content_type` or `object_pk` when rendering your form. Check in your rendered form that you have those fields. Maybe you will find the problem after reading [Notes on the comment form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#notes-on-the-comment-form).

Comment: thanks for the answer! i was checking the documentation once again. i realised that i forgot to add {% get_comment_form for [object] as [varname] %} when i wanted to load customized form.